# Is there a way to set a ConsoleColor value equal to a variable?

Tags: c#, colors, background, console, foreground

I am working on creating a class to support a console app I am developing, and I would like to create a method within to change both the background and foreground color.  Is there a way to set a ConsoleColor value (which I believe is an enum) to another variable so this can easily be changed by the user at runtime?  For instance, I am hoping for something like the following.

```
Public class ConsoleOutput
{
  private var consoleBackground = ConsoleColor.White;
  private var consoleForeground = ConsoleColor.Black;
  
  Public ConsoleOutput
  {
    Console.BackgroundColor = consoleBackground
    Console.ForegroundColor = consoleForeground
  }
}
```

This, however, did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to ever write to the console in your program, which you obviously need to do. Other then that you also need a way to change the colors during runtime using e.g. setters or a function like `ChangeColors()`.

Here a working sample program for reference:

```cs
namespace MyProgram;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var coloredPrinter = new ColoredPrinter(ConsoleColor.White, ConsoleColor.Blue);
        coloredPrinter.WriteLine("This is white text on blue background");
        coloredPrinter.ChangeColors(ConsoleColor.Yellow, ConsoleColor.Red);
        coloredPrinter.WriteLine("This is yellow text on red background");
        Console.WriteLine("This is the default");
    }
}

class ColoredPrinter
{
    public ConsoleColor ForegroundColor { get; set; }
    public ConsoleColor BackgroundColor { get; set; }

    public ColoredPrinter(ConsoleColor foregroundColor, ConsoleColor backgroundColor)
    {
        ChangeColors(foregroundColor, backgroundColor);
    }

    public void ChangeColors(ConsoleColor foregroundColor, ConsoleColor backgroundColor)
    {
        ForegroundColor = foregroundColor;
        BackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    }

    public void WriteLine(string text)
    {
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.BackgroundColor = BackgroundColor;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ForegroundColor;
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}
```

This prints out the following:

[image: colored console output]